# Dynamic addition of graphs in Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dygraphs

I am using Dygraphs for one of my applications. I am new to it. I read the docs and a few examples to see how it works. So from the docs, I could see that the constructor for Dygraphs requires a `div` section where the graph will be inserted. For example, consider http://jsfiddle.net/dygraphs/NtBPk/. However, my objective is to generate a graph dynamically upon a button click. That said, I can have more than one graph, that too dynamically created. So how do I do that?

Any explanations with changes in the given jsfiddle are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Dygraph object whenever the button is clicked. You'll want one Dygraph object per chart.